Routing issue with dual WiFi hotspots: One through Wireguard VPN, one direct
Environment

OS: Linux
Network interfaces:

wlan0: Used for non-VPN hotspot (MyHotspot)
wlan1: Connected to internet
wlan2: Used for VPN hotspot (MyHotspot-VPN)
au-syd-wg-002: Wireguard VPN interface



Configuration
I have set up two WiFi hotspots:

MyHotspot (non-VPN): Using wlan0, internet from wlan1
MyHotspot-VPN: Using wlan2, internet through Wireguard VPN (au-syd-wg-002)

Wireguard configuration (/etc/wireguard/au-syd-wg-002.conf):
[Interface]
PrivateKey = redacted
Address = 10.67.48.249/32,fc00:bbbb:bbbb:bb01::4:30f8/128
DNS = 10.64.0.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = redacted
AllowedIPs = 192.168.13.0/24
Endpoint = 146.70.141.194:51820

MyHotspot (non-VPN) configuration (/etc/create_ap/wlan0-1.conf):
GATEWAY=192.168.12.1
DHCP_DNS=gateway
WIFI_IFACE=wlan0
INTERNET_IFACE=wlan1
SSID=MyHotspot

MyHotspot-VPN configuration (/etc/create_ap/wlan2-vpn.conf):
GATEWAY=192.168.13.1
DHCP_DNS=10.64.0.1
WIFI_IFACE=wlan2
INTERNET_IFACE=au-syd-wg-002
SSID=MyHotspot-VPN

Network interface details (ifconfig output):
au-syd-wg-002: flags=209<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 1420
        inet 10.67.48.249  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 10.67.48.249
        inet6 fc00:bbbb:bbbb:bb01::4:30f8  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.12.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.12.255
        inet6 fe80::dea6:32ff:fe9a:b7b2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether dc:a6:32:9a:b7:b2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 70838  bytes 11884831 (11.3 MiB)
        TX packets 118247  bytes 112432350 (107.2 MiB)

wlan1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.35.157  netmask 255.255.252.0  broadcast 172.17.35.255
        inet6 fe80::280a:74a5:f28a:341d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether f0:09:0d:36:7b:7a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 118170  bytes 112463238 (107.2 MiB)
        TX packets 68718  bytes 14022513 (13.3 MiB)

wlan2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.13.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.13.255
        inet6 fe80::3698:b5ff:fe36:9bf5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 34:98:b5:36:9b:f5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 121  bytes 18670 (18.2 KiB)
        TX packets 101  bytes 19478 (19.0 KiB)

Routing table:
default via 172.17.32.10 dev wlan1 proto dhcp src 172.17.35.157 metric 600 
172.17.32.0/22 dev wlan1 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.35.157 metric 600 
192.168.12.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.12.1 
192.168.13.0/24 dev au-syd-wg-002 scope link 
192.168.13.0/24 dev wlan2 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.13.1 

Issue
The non-VPN hotspot works fine, but the VPN hotspot doesn't work. When connecting to MyHotspot-VPN, I get a DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET error on browser requests.
However, if I change the AllowedIPs in the Wireguard config to 0.0.0.0/0, both hotspots work fine, but then both are routed through the VPN. I only want MyHotspot-VPN to use the Wireguard VPN.
Question
How can I configure my routing or Wireguard setup to allow the MyHotspot-VPN hotspot (wlan2) to properly route traffic through the Wireguard VPN (au-syd-wg-002) while keeping the MyHotspot hotspot (wlan0) on the regular internet connection?
Additional Information

The VPN hotspot is configured to use the VPN's DNS (10.64.0.1), as can be noticed in the config file
Both hotspots are created using the linux-wifi-hotspot tool, and here is an example of a default create_ap.conf file

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

You need AllowedIPs=0.0.0.0/0 anyway, because otherwise WG will have no idea where to send the traffics. You probably want to start with adding Table=off in the [Interface] section. If this linux-wifi-hotspot whatsoever leverages policy routing for you, then it might just work. (I hope that it set up MSS fix for you as well btw.)
